# Changing resolution in another app moves widgets on desktop

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution, minecraft, widgets

So Im using a 1920x1080 display on my laptop. I only use the laptop (no monitors) and When I play Minecraft in order to make the GUI look better I have to change the games resolution to 1366x736 (it has an ingame option for it) but the problem is whenever I do that the widgets that I have on my desktop completely move out of where they were, ive tried locking the widgets but not even that works. I need a solution because everytime i play I have to keep moving the widgets back to where they were

I am on Kubuntu 22.04